# Repeat list endlessly (Zip a finite list with an Infinite repeating sequence)

Tags: c#, linq

`UserList` is a list of dictionaries, like:

```
[
  {Name:"Alex",Age:25},
  {Name:"Peter",Age:35},
  {Name:"Muhammad",Age:28},
  {Name:"Raul",Age:29}
]
```

`RowColorList` is a list of colors: `[#bcf,#fc0]`

The new `UserList` should contain one `RowColor` for every name, taken in sequence from `RowColorList`:

```
[
  {Name:"Alex",Age:25,RowColor:#bcf},
  {Name:"Peter",Age:35,RowColor:#fc0},
  {Name:"Muhammad",Age:28,RowColor:#bcf},
  {Name:"Raul",Age:29,RowColor:#fc0}
]
```

I tried the following code:

```
UserList.Zip(RowColorList,(user,color) => user.Add("RowColor",color))
```

With this code, the new `UserList` will only contain as many entries as are in `RowColorList`. I would like him to start from the beginning of `RowColorList` again, whenever the available colors are used up. How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a function to return an infinite enumerable of `Color` / `string` (or whatever the type of `RowColor` is), by using `yield return` as a lazy generator:

```
public IEnumerable<Color> InfiniteColors()
{
    while (true)
    {   
        foreach (var color in RowColors)
        {
            yield return color;
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be used with any of the Linq `IEnumerable` extension methods such as `Zip`.

```
UserList.Zip(InfiniteColors(),(user,color) => user.Add("RowColor",color))
```

**Edit - Explanation**

The reason why `InfiniteColors` doesn't hang is because the state machine will yield back to the caller after each result, and Zip will terminate on the first enumerable to complete, which is because the other collection being zipped is finite (i.e. `UserList`)

Obviously you shouldn't try and `Zip` the `InfiniteColors` enumerable with itself, nor should you try and materialize `InfiniteColors`, i.e. don't call `InfiniteColors.ToList()` or such :-):

Comment: did you try it? Why doesn't it run forever?

Comment: @VMAtm Because `Zip` stops when either sequence runs out.

Comment: @VMatm - the state machine [will yield back to the caller after each result](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx), and `Zip` will terminate on the first enumerable to complete, which will be the finite `UserList`. Obviously you shouldn't try and `Zip` the `InfiniteColors` enumerable with itself :)

Comment: I will do as you proposed, but for better recycling, I will try to implement it as a generic extension method: `UserList.Zip(colors.GetInfiniteEnumerable(),...`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var i = 0;
var l = RowColorList.Count;
UserList.ForEach(user => user.Add("RowColor", RowColorList[(i++) % l]));
```

[The % operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) will guarantee "cyclic" access to the RowColorList.