# How to distribute a large range of values over a smaller range of values

Tags: algorithm, list, object

I want to take a list with, for example, eight objects and want to distribute them evenly over a property of a smaller list of four objects.

Example:

```
var listLarge = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];
var listSmall = [objA, objB];
```

Result should be something like this:

```
var distributed = [obj1 {prop = objA}, obj2 {prop = objB},
     obj3 {prop = objA}, obj4 {prop = objB}];
```

I tried some nested for loops but it did not really work out and felt smelly.

Comment: Please fix your tags; there's nothing about C#, LINQ, or Combine here.

Comment: @DourHighArch too late :) but really [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108086/repeat-list-endlessly-zip-a-finite-list-with-an-infinite-repeating-sequence) shows  reasonable algorithm in C# LINQ anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much - next time I will try harder to look it up - but sometimes you miss the right words to find something! ;)